# Autofs and udev rules to restrict usb permissions to groups

Tags: groups, usb, sles, autofs, udev

I need some help trying  to figure out how to restrict the reading and writing access of usb devices.
There are two groups on my system:

- usbreaders: only should have rights to access and read the usb
  content.
- usbwriters: should have reading and writing rights on the usb content.

I configured the following udev rule to create a symbolic link of the storage device attached:

> */etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules*

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",DRIVERS=="usb-storage",SYMLINK+="USB_MASS_STORAGE%n"
```

Then I configured autofs to mount the usb content with different permissions to two different folders:

> */etc/auto.master.d/auto-USB.autofs*

```
MY_USB       -fstype=auto    :/dev/USB_MASS_STORAGE1
```

> /etc/auto.master

```
/USBRO  /etc/auto.master.d/auto-USB.autofs --timeout=10,noexec,nosuid,uid=root,gid=usbreaders,fmask=127,dmask=027
/USBRW  /etc/auto.master.d/auto-USB.autofs --timeout=10,noexec,nosuid,uid=root,gid=usbwriters,fmask=007,dmask=007
+auto.master
```

But something weird happens. Permissions changes automatically, sometimes owns to usbwriters and sometimes to usbreaders o both folders... really weird.

Could anybody give me ha hand with this?
Thank you, really aprecciated!